# hidden folders in Internet

Tags: webserver

very often in Internet I see links like this:

```
www.abcde.com/~main/material/hello
```

and this part `~main/material/hello` is grey, if I remove `hello` I receive access forbidden, can somebody explain, what is this system, and is it possible receive access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean it is grey? the link text on a page? That can be any colour that the page owner wants, but I don't remember seeing a grey link.

What happens if you type www.abcde.com/~main/material/hello directly into the browser's address window?

If you remove "hello" and receive access forbidden it is because there is no public access to www.abcde.com/~main/materia - give up, you will never access that without a password.

Answer (score 1):

Directory listing is disallowed on `www.abcde.com/~main/material/`, but you have access to it's content.

Answer (score 1):

They've configured the web server to only allow access to certain areas. You won't be able to receive access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the web server. On [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) this can be done with

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: sorry, but what does it mean Options -Indexes
, where to enter it?

Comment: In the Apache config file, or in a .htaccess file in the directory in question. Read the Apache documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (`~`) is *nix convention for a user's home directory. Using it in the URL tells an [appropriately-configured web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir) to look in a directory in the user's home directory for the files to show via the web server.